# Missing information from Child Process in Node

Tags: node.js, linux, child-process, spawn

i'm running a Counter-Strike: Source Dedicated Server with Node.js through the Child Process module like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const server = spawn('./srcds_run', ['-game cstrike', '+map de_dust2', '+maxplayers 10'])
server.on('error', function (error){
    console.log(error);
});
server.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`server stdout:\n${data}`);
});
server.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`server stderr:\n${data}`);
});
```

The server runs perfectly fine, i can join to it and play, but i got missing information that the server must return in the console.

If i run the server mannualy from the console it show all [this info](https://pastebin.com/d92rsf40).
But if i run it fron this Node app only shows [this info](https://pastebin.com/MseKXPV5)
(I used pastebin because there was too many lines to paste directly here)

I'm missing the most important info that i want, which are all the lines that start with the `L` character, they are the server logs that tells me all what's happening in every match.

I read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and i couldn't find anything about it, and also tryed with listeners like `message` and `log` but any of them retrieve info.

Any idea how get all this info? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to stream console output to file? This way you could at least check which stream these lines belong to. The problem may be not specific to Node.

Comment: No, i didn't, could you explain me a little bit more that? Last night i was playing with the `stdio` options and i've be able to get those missing lines when i used `inherit` but, they are showed outside the streamers just like if i ran the server through the console

Comment: Try to run the command as `srcds_run > stdout.txt`, etc. from shell.

Comment: Well, every `std*` save the same info, the [first three lines](https://pastebin.com/MseKXPV5) and nothing more

Comment: I think the problem is that, `srcds_run` run another process called `srcds_linux` as it say in the second line, if `srcds_linux` is the process that runs the server itself (and print the logs) i should read the `stdout` of the subprocess of my subprocess... Well, this is getting hard

Comment: I ended up adding `logaddress_add ip:port` on the `server.cfg` game file and read all the data in the server with a datagram socket, isn't the way i wanted, but it works. If some day i can reach my original goal i'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'd expect that spawn exposes nested streams as server.std* the same way it propagates them to process.std* on `stdio: inherit`, so this needs some investigation.

Comment: I'm doing the investigation cause the solution i found would require more code in order to work properly so i think worth studie deeper the first approach. I can confirm after read the content of `srcds_run` and execute a lot of `pgrep`, `ps` and `top` commands that `srcds_run` is just an script that receive parameters, then execute `srcds_linux` (depend on the OS) and that is the server itself, in fact, you can kill the `srcds_run` process and `srcds_linux` will keep runing and logging info into the terminal while you play

Comment: @estus sorry for bothering you, if you're still interested, i answered my own question with the solution i found

Comment: Makes sense. It's a good thing the solution was straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

1. This Node.js program just execute the server with Child Process
2. Once the server is running the communication is made directly throught the [RCON Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol)

Simple as that, i don't need to build a gigantic program from scratch, with the RCON Protocol i can read all the output and send commands just like i do from the ingame console.